# PHP remove duplicate multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, duplicates

This is the input array that I am going to use to filter.

```
[TESTING] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [a] => false
                [b] => WCP
                [c] => Title A
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [a] => false
                [b] => WCP
                [c] => Title B
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [a] => false
                [b] => WCP
                [c] => Title C
            )

    )
```

I want to remove duplicate records that have both: keys [a] and [b] have the same value. I don't want to use [c] as a condition to remove duplicate records. The output in this case should be.

```
[TESTING] => Array
    (
    )
```

Cause all 3 subarrays have values of key [a] and key [b] are the same value. I used `array_unique()` but this function use all 3 [a], [b] and [c] as the conditions to remove duplicate records which I don't want. I don't get the output as I want.

Need help. Any suggestions or idea?

Comment: array_unique compares things as a whole. you can't tell it to ignore components of what you're comparing. you'll have to cobble together something yourself, e.g. `array_walk()`.

Comment: What output array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution to your problem, if you found it useful:-

```
<?php $a = array(
        0 => array(
                "a" => false,
                "b" => "WCP",
                "c" => "Title A"
            ),
        1 => array(
                "a" => false,
                "b" => "WCP",
                "c" => "Title B"
            ),
            2 => array(
                "a" => false,
                "b" => "WCP",
                "c" => "Title C"
            )
        );
global $checkArray;
$checkArray = $a;
function array_remove($a){
  global $checkArray;
  $arrLen = count($checkArray);
  unset($a['c']);
  foreach ($checkArray as $key => $value) {
    $diff = array_diff($value, $a);
    if (1 != count($diff) ||  !array_key_exists('c', $diff)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
print_r(array_filter($a, "array_remove"));
```

Comment: @DanielDucTrinh oh Thanks, If it solves your query, can accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

The array functions in PHP are primarily designed for 2D arrays.  You will need to iterate over the multidimensional array, conduct a comparison of key values, and then assign the correct results to a holding array.  The holding array would need a scope that would allow multiple iterations through the upper level of the multidimensional array.  This could be done as a function used with array_filter; or, done by standalone reassignment.

Comment: Thanks...that what i am trying todo

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function clearDuplicates($array)
{
   $new_array=array();

    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
    {
        $x=false;
        for($j=0;$j<count($array);$j++)
        if($j!=$i)
            if($array[$i]["a"]==$array[$j]["a"] && $array[$i]["b"]==$array[$j]["b"])
                $x=true;

        if(!$x)
            $new_array[]=$array[$i];
     }  

    return new_array;
}
```